Maui Android Auto app using Xamarin Media Manager doesn't launch from car unless launched from app first
We've got a media app which has been made using .net Maui, with the media portion implemented by Xamarin Media Manager. We've made some modifications to fix some issues but for the most part it's as-is. We're currently working on making an Android Auto interface - this has mostly been smooth sailing, Xamarin Media Manager has already implemented a MediaBrowserService which we've been able to hook into to display our UI on the car interface.
However one strange issue we've come across is that it seems like launching the app from Android Auto will result in a blank screen with no content - unless the app is launched from the phone first, at which point it'll run fine until you force-close the app and then it'll revert to its odd state of unusability. I assume something is wrong with the MediaBrowserService within Xamarin Media Manager but I'm at a loss as to what exactly - it doesn't really feel there should be much room to have it not work as expected.
Our Android Manifest contains the necessary car stuff:
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.car.application" android:resource="@xml/automotive_app_desc" />
<meta-data android:name="androidx.car.app.minCarApiLevel" android:value="6" />

Our automotive app is as so:
<automotiveApp>
    <uses name="media"/>
</automotiveApp>

Our Xamarin media manager MediaBrowserService is slightly modified, but largely close to the original as on their Github
Thanks in advance - we're so close to being ready to launch if not for this one issue.
